# Off putting comments and remarks

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-flags, community-standards

Firstly I would like to say that as a learner I am deeply indebted to Stack Overflow and it has saved me many sleepness nights but I have found that I am sometimes reluctant to post a question, no matter how desperate I am for the answer, for fear of being patronised by other members.

There maybe times when I don't phrase a question as well as perhaps I might, but that would be because I am learning about the language I'm asking the question about and I don't know the 'correct' way to phrase it.  And the same goes for searching for answers.  I always search for an answer first because I want to work it out for myself but sometimes I don't know how to phrase the question, draw a blank, post the question and get marked down for not looking or asking a duplicate.  Answers that consist of just links to the php manual with a comment telling me I should have read it doesn't help either, I would have looked there before posting and not been able to understand how to put the answer in context with my problem.

There are times when I ask a question and people are very quick to make sarcastic comments about how I edited it etc and mark it down whether it has any bearing on the actual question or answer.

Like I said, I am very grateful to this site and this is not meant in anyway to be a criticism but more a request for other users to be more tolerant of newbies like myself rather than making them feel intimidated and not wanting to post, which is sometimes how I and other Stack Overflow users that I know feel.  The idea is to encourage learners, not put them off.

Comment: If comments are made which are "not nice", flag them. Constructive comments are fine, but anything rude or offensive is not. And that's why we have flags.

Comment: If you mean comments such as noting that Java isn't the same as Javascript, I fail to see how you can think that has no bearing on the question.

Comment: If you read the comments I had made a mistake when I added the categories but instead of pointing this out a sarcastic comment was made leaving me wonder what they were talking about.  I thought they were making a comment about my code. And this is exactly what I mean, I am saying something that I am unhappy about, making a friendly comment about it, and I'm just being told I'm wrong to be unhappy about it

Comment: @tatty27 Well, it's pointless to be unhappy about it. Try to understand it and once you do, move on. There no point in getting worked up over stuff on the intarwebs. And as said, if it truly gets out of hand, let moderators deal with it and move on. The comment Jon is referring to is not really something I would flag. If you don't get it, just ask what is meant. And that's it...

Comment: If you have some specific examples, please share links, as hostile and other "not nice" comments should be removed, but from a couple of questions of yours I looked at, I think you need to develop a thicker skin.  The `java != javascript` comment could have been phrased more constructively but it is very mild compared to some of the bad comments I have seen around here

Comment: @psubsee2003 you're right that the comment was mild, I guess it was because I sat here for while debating whether or not to post that question because of the reasons stated in this post and sure enough, within seconds, that comment was made.  It didn't help when I'd told him it was a mistake and he then replied saying "mistake" implying that it hadn't been.  Thanks for listening and I'll grow a thicker skin.  Like I said before, this isn't a complaint, this site has helped me no end in both my work and my studying

Comment: @tatty27 one of the things I have learned is the community expects asking a question on Stack Overflow be the last resort.  Where the last resort idea becomes a problem is a last resort for someone new who might not know the right keywords is very different for someone experienced.  Combine that with the new users who don't care to do their own research and/or learn the guidelines of the community, you end up with people who leave very terse comments.  The best advice I can offer is what everyone has suggested.  Don't let it bother you so much.  Take the comment, learn from it, and move on.

Comment: ^^ What tatty27 said.  Don't be so sensitive.  Also, maybe try asking a question like: "What's the best way to phrase the following question?"  (I hope that doesn't get me downvoted, because it seemed like a decent idea, and useful for a broad community)... Which gets me thinking... Should we start "Beginners" forums?